# How to ignore a property that is a member in the parent class?

Tags: protobuf-net

I've a class that has a `[ProtoMember]` on one virtual property.
In a child class, this property only returns a constants string, and throw an exception when being set. I added the  `[ProtoIgnore]` on it, but ProtoBuf still tries to serialize it.

Is there a way to avoid this?

Note: Due to reasons external of protobuf(framework of undo-redo) I cannot use a backingfield in the property of my parent class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add to the base-class:

```
public virtual bool ShouldSerializeFoo() => true;
```

(for your property name `Foo`), then in the sub-class where you don't want to serialize it:

```
public override bool ShouldSerializeFoo() => false;
```

Comment: I was not aware of this, great. Just worried that I've to do this often for 5-10 fields